# One UR5 executing all commands in a 2 UR5 system

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use moveit to control two UR5 robots in a script. However, one robot is executing all commands sent to both robots. Could anyone point out where my issue is? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Here is my moveit controller.yaml file:

```
controller_list:
  - name: "/frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller"
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - shoulder_pan_joint
      - shoulder_lift_joint
      - elbow_joint
      - wrist_1_joint
      - wrist_2_joint
      - wrist_3_joint
  - name: "/klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller"
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - shoulder_pan_joint
      - shoulder_lift_joint
      - elbow_joint
      - wrist_1_joint
      - wrist_2_joint
      - wrist_3_joint
```

And my launch file for launching moveit planning for both robots:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="frank">
   <arg name="sim" default="true" />
   <arg name="limited" default="false"/>
   <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <include file="$(find ur5_moveit_config)/launch/ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch">
   <arg name="sim" value="$(arg sim)"/>
   <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
   <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>
 </group>

 <group ns="klaus">
   <arg name="sim" default="true" />
   <arg name="limited" default="false"/>
   <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <include file="$(find ur5_moveit_config)/launch/ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch">
   <arg name="sim" value="$(arg sim)"/>
   <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
   <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>
 </group>

</launch>
```

Below is the console when I run the above launch file then try and `klaus` a goal (`frank` tries to take it)

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/9daf99e89f37b2644ec87d24f7c8f744

And part of my script I'm using to declare both robots:

```
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_x2', anonymous=True)

klaus_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = "/klaus/robot_description", ns = "klaus")
frank_commander = moveit_commander.RobotCommander(robot_description = "/frank/robot_description", ns = "klaus")
scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()

group_name = "manipulator" #manipulator in gazebo
klaus_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name, "/klaus/robot_description", "klaus")
frank_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name, "/frank/robot_description", "klaus")

#display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path',
# moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,
#                                               queue_size=20)

self.klaus_commander = klaus_commander
self.frank_commander = frank_commander
self.scene = scene
self.klaus_group = klaus_group
self.frank_group = frank_group
#self.display_trajectory_publisher = display_trajectory_publisher

self.klaus_home_joints = [-1.8963, -0.5800, -2.2339, -1.8976, 1.5629, 2.0322] #self.group.remember_joint_values()
self.frank_home_joints = [1.9018, -2.5591,  2.2402,   -1.2513, -1.5875,  2.6912]
```

My `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` seems to be able to recognize two distinct robots. Below is a printout of the result of my launch file

```
team-sewts@sewts-Legion:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch ur_robot_driver x2_ur5_bringup.launch
... logging to /home/team-sewts/.ros/log/679066c4-1cc0-11ea-9d94-98eecb87900f/roslaunch-sewts-Legion-11570.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://sewts-Legion:44913/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /frank/controller_stopper/consistent_controllers: ['joint_state_con...
 * /frank/force_torque_sensor_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /frank/force_torque_sensor_controller/type: force_torque_sens...
 * /frank/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /frank/hardware_interface/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /frank/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /frank/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /frank/pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /frank/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /frank/scaled_pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /frank/speed_scaling_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /frank/speed_scaling_state_controller/type: ur_controllers/Sp...
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/headless_mode: False
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/input_recipe_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/pitch: 0.00093885655167
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/roll: 0.0024488787422
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/x: -0.425237485479
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/y: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/yaw: 6.46670270587e-05
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/z: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/hash: calib_17806549593...
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/pitch: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/roll: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/x: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/y: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/yaw: 5.79279161283e-06
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/z: 0.0891146992347
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/pitch: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/roll: 1.56991820726
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/x: 0.000119121831423
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/y: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/yaw: 3.76452354309e-05
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/z: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/pitch: 3.14047178922
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/roll: 3.12614865807
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/x: -0.392086900423
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/y: 0.00170729307315
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/yaw: 3.14157131922
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/z: 0.110538579795
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/pitch: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/roll: 1.57083797096
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/x: 0.000107330035296
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/y: -0.0949150748051
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/yaw: -8.54146891712e-05
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/z: -3.95265927847e-06
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/pitch: 3.14159265359
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/roll: 1.57133146853
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/x: -4.72678055337e-05
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/y: 0.0826952361665
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/yaw: 3.14145640841
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/z: 4.42536767553e-05
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/output_recipe_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/reverse_port: 50003
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/robot_ip: 169.254.198.38
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/script_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/script_sender_port: 50004
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tf_prefix: frank_
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_baud_rate: 115200
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_parity: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_rx_idle_chars: 1.5
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_stop_bits: 1
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_tx_idle_chars: 3.5
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/tool_voltage: 0
 * /frank/ur_hardware_interface/use_tool_communication: False
 * /klaus/controller_stopper/consistent_controllers: ['joint_state_con...
 * /klaus/force_torque_sensor_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /klaus/force_torque_sensor_controller/type: force_torque_sens...
 * /klaus/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /klaus/hardware_interface/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /klaus/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /klaus/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /klaus/pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /klaus/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.2
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/state_publish_rate: 125
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /klaus/scaled_pos_traj_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /klaus/speed_scaling_state_controller/publish_rate: 125
 * /klaus/speed_scaling_state_controller/type: ur_controllers/Sp...
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/headless_mode: False
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/input_recipe_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/pitch: 0.000670340723934
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/roll: 0.000150389826896
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/x: -0.425316567681
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/y: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/yaw: -0.000129296667033
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/forearm/z: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/hash: calib_72470218391...
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/pitch: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/roll: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/x: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/y: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/yaw: 8.77666344309e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/shoulder/z: 0.0893072092318
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/pitch: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/roll: 1.57027963108
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/x: 8.02597230883e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/y: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/yaw: -0.000256378975585
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/upper_arm/z: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/pitch: 3.139985598
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/roll: 3.13404114506
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/x: -0.392232740578
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/y: 0.000835269385168
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/yaw: 3.14149191057
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_1/z: 0.110607503694
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/pitch: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/roll: 1.57084155987
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/x: 3.88210393792e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/y: -0.0949976987238
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/yaw: 5.57612237128e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_2/z: -4.2970377454e-06
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/pitch: 3.14159265359
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/roll: 1.57047457779
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/x: 7.18408705395e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/y: 0.0828382643859
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/yaw: -3.14148013852
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/kinematics/wrist_3/z: -2.66531297376e-05
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/output_recipe_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/reverse_port: 50001
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/robot_ip: 169.254.198.35
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/script_file: /home/team-sewts/...
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/script_sender_port: 50002
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tf_prefix: klaus_
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_baud_rate: 115200
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_parity: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_rx_idle_chars: 1.5
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_stop_bits: 1
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_tx_idle_chars: 3.5
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/tool_voltage: 0
 * /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/use_tool_communication: False
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /klaus/ur_hardware_interface/
    ur_robot_state_helper (ur_robot_driver/robot_state_helper)
  /frank/
    controller_stopper (controller_stopper/node)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ros_control_stopped_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ur_hardware_interface (ur_robot_driver/ur_robot_driver_node)
  /klaus/
    controller_stopper (controller_stopper/node)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ros_control_stopped_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ur_hardware_interface (ur_robot_driver/ur_robot_driver_node)
  /frank/ur_hardware_interface/
    ur_robot_state_helper (ur_robot_driver/robot_state_helper)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [11586]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 679066c4-1cc0-11ea-9d94-98eecb87900f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11599]
started core service [/rosout]
process[frank/robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [11616]
process[frank/ur_hardware_interface-3]: started with pid [11617]
process[frank/ros_control_controller_spawner-4]: started with pid [11618]
process[frank/ros_control_stopped_spawner-5]: started with pid [11630]
process[frank/controller_stopper-6]: started with pid [11650]
[ INFO] [1576142329.540665935]: Initializing dashboard client
[ INFO] [1576142329.541867394]: Connected: Universal Robots Dashboard Server

process[frank/ur_hardware_interface/ur_robot_state_helper-7]: started with pid [11672]
process[klaus/robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [11685]
[ INFO] [1576142329.550129157]: Waiting for controller manager service to come up on /frank/controller_manager/switch_controller
[ INFO] [1576142329.550944198]: waitForService: Service [/frank/controller_manager/switch_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
process[klaus/ur_hardware_interface-9]: started with pid [11706]
process[klaus/ros_control_controller_spawner-10]: started with pid [11725]
process[klaus/ros_control_stopped_spawner-11]: started with pid [11746]
process[klaus/controller_stopper-12]: started with pid [11759]
[ INFO] [1576142329.571441911]: Initializing urdriver
[ INFO] [1576142329.571707276]: Checking if calibration data matches connected robot.
[ WARN] [1576142329.572020243]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
process[klaus/ur_hardware_interface/ur_robot_state_helper-13]: started with pid [11777]
[ INFO] [1576142329.592535945]: Waiting for controller manager service to come up on /klaus/controller_manager/switch_controller
[ INFO] [1576142329.593517787]: waitForService: Service [/klaus/controller_manager/switch_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1576142329.593910381]: Initializing dashboard client
[ INFO] [1576142329.595570926]: Connected: Universal Robots Dashboard Server

[ INFO] [1576142329.622194133]: Initializing urdriver
[ INFO] [1576142329.622456125]: Checking if calibration data matches connected robot.
[ WARN] [1576142329.622677137]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1576142329.735688831]: Calibration checked successfully.
[INFO] [1576142329.781395]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1576142329.785118]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1576142329.823188]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1576142329.824744]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1576142330.057359613]: Calibration checked successfully.
[ WARN] [1576142330.637896831]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ WARN] [1576142330.658888696]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1576142330.782284457]: Setting up RTDE communication with frequency 125.000000
[ INFO] [1576142331.182071053]: Setting up RTDE communication with frequency 125.000000
[ WARN] [1576142331.825949950]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1576142331.826125603]: Loaded ur_robot_driver hardware_interface
[ INFO] [1576142331.880527340]: waitForService: Service [/frank/controller_manager/switch_controller] is now available.
[ INFO] [1576142331.880553237]: Service available.
[ INFO] [1576142331.880568036]: Waiting for controller list service to come up on /frank/controller_manager/list_controllers
[ INFO] [1576142331.881184179]: Service available.
[INFO] [1576142331.904572]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.905566]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.906479]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.907063]: Loading controller: pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.907368]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.908317]: Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.936089]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.943950]: Loading controller: scaled_pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.983925]: Loading controller: speed_scaling_state_controller
[INFO] [1576142331.991901]: Loading controller: force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.000013]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.007943]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[ INFO] [1576142332.030176625]: Robot's safety mode is now NORMAL
[ INFO] [1576142332.030314579]: Robot mode is now RUNNING
[ WARN] [1576142332.240319884]: No realtime capabilities found. Consider using a realtime system for better performance
[ INFO] [1576142332.240549722]: Loaded ur_robot_driver hardware_interface
[ INFO] [1576142332.304204558]: waitForService: Service [/klaus/controller_manager/switch_controller] is now available.
[ INFO] [1576142332.304224389]: Service available.
[ INFO] [1576142332.304235401]: Waiting for controller list service to come up on /klaus/controller_manager/list_controllers
[ INFO] [1576142332.304796701]: Service available.
[ INFO] [1576142332.507056757]: Robot's safety mode is now NORMAL
[ INFO] [1576142332.507557813]: Robot mode is now RUNNING
[INFO] [1576142332.551235]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.552829]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.555047]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.556541]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.558815]: Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.560235]: Loading controller: pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.575660]: Loading controller: scaled_pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.639357]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_traj_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.703469]: Loading controller: speed_scaling_state_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.711402]: Loading controller: force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.719337]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1576142332.727428]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339768/one-ur5-executing-all-commands-in-a-2-ur5-system/) by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[As described here](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/45)

Along with [this merge](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/pull/57), the namespacing in the script I wrote was incorrect and the controllers.yaml file only needed one controller in it. However, this results in the same issue as [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/318683/using-two-arms-with-moveit-unable-to-get-joints-for-both/)

---

Originally posted by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) with karma: 64 on 2020-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1